# Transparent button showing an image in GTK3

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk

I'm using GTK3 with python and I would like to have a  button with transparent background while showing a png image. set_opacity does'nt work because this also makes de image transparent.

I need my button to look like this:
http://i1276.photobucket.com/albums/y472/Cristhian_Eduardo_Fuertes_Daza/buttonJ_zps4c1d177c.png

But instead mine looks like this:
http://i1276.photobucket.com/albums/y472/Cristhian_Eduardo_Fuertes_Daza/buttonP_zps53f8f3ea.png

What I want is really easy to do in Java using the method setContentAreaFill but I don´t know how to get the same result in python using GTK

Answer (score 1):

You can try hardcoded it or make custom css and call it within your python code. The css button class should have the "background-image" and/or "background-color" with 100% transparent.